# Matrix powers and hyperbola

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-curves

(We're in $\mathbb{R}^2$) How to find hyperbola equation, that has symmetry axis crossing (0,0) point and for $n=1,2,\ldots$ points ${\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}^n \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ lie on that hyperbola, also how to show that all those points lie on it?

By those points I mean $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $n=1$, $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $n=2$, etc.

So far I've tried diagonalization of $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, but it's very messy and I don't know where it could get me to be honest. I guess that hyperbola can be rotated.

Edit:
So knowing that in $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$ we got $E=F=0$ and choosing $F=-1$ we have

$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 = 1$ and substituting $x=0$, $y=1$ we have $C=1$, again substituting $x=3$, $y=1$ we have $B = -3A$ and again $x=15$, $y=4$ we finally obtain $15^2A -15\cdot 4 \cdot 3A = -15$, so $15A-12A=-1$, thus $A=-\frac{1}{3}$ and $B=1$,

so our curve is
$-\frac{1}{3}x^2 + xy + y^2 - 1 = 0$

Now we can easly check what curve is it using quadratic forms.
Let $Q(X) = -\frac{1}{3}x^2 + xy + y^2$, then our curve is $Q(X) - 1 = 0$

Now $\mathrm{m}(Q) = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, so

$\chi_{\mathrm{m}(Q)}(x) = x^2 + \frac{2}{3}x - \frac{4}{3}$,

$\lambda = \frac{-1-\sqrt{13}}{3}$, $\mu= \frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{3}$,

thus $Q(X) = PDP^{-1} = P \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1-\sqrt{13}}{3} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{3} \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}$, so in new base we have

$\frac{-1-\sqrt{13}}{3} (x')^2 + \frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{3}(y')^2 - 1 = 0$, so

$$\frac{(x')^2}{\left ( \sqrt{\frac{3}{\sqrt{13} + 1}} \right )^2} - \frac{(y')^2}{\left ( \sqrt{\frac{3}{\sqrt{13} - 1}} \right )^2} = -1$$
and our curve is hyperbola.

Comment: Well, there’s a brute-force solution: generate the first five points and use the fact that five points in general position define a conic.

Comment: @amd Sure, but how to do that and why five points and not four for example? This task shouldn't be that hard I guess, I mean it was on my exam on very first university term.

Comment: It’s five points because the general conic equation $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ has five degrees of freedom. Plug the points that you’ve generated into this equation and solve the resulting linear system for the unknown coefficients. Doesn’t sound very hard to me.

Comment: Come to think of it, you’re given that the hyperbola is centered at the origin, so $D=E=0$ and you can choose $F=-1$, so three points will suffice.

Comment: @amd Okay, I updated my question, is it okay now?

Comment: You don’t need to convert the equation into standard form in order to find out what type of conic it represents. Just check the discriminant (which is a multiple of the determinant of $m(Q)$). You haven’t yet verified that _all_ of the points lie on the hyperbola.

Comment: @amd How I could know that by discriminant? I don't know that method. Also, how to verify that all points lie on it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant. This is a basic thing that one learns when studying conics. As for verifying that all of the points lie on the hyperbola, you could work out a general formula for them—this is something that you should’ve learned how to do in the linear algebra course—and plug the result into the hyperbola’s equation. Or... just bet that they do.

Comment: BTW, the matrix that you have for $m(Q)$ doesn’t match $Q$.